# Show HTML elements on demand with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

TL;DR : I'm trying to find a way to handle HTML injections into the DOM to avoid having to include irrelevant code in the DOM at all times.

---

I have a large PHP application that has several forms and modals through out the pages of the application. I'm trying to find a way to lessen the DOM elements by only showing/adding elements as and when they're needed.

What I have so far looks something like this:

```
<body>
    
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <main>
        
        <a href="#" class="ismodal" data-modal="login">Click to access modal</a>

    </main>
    <!-- / Page Content -->

    <div class="modalContainer">
    
        <div class="modal" id="modal-login">
            <!-- modal content -->
        </div>
    
        <div class="modal" id="modal-register">
            <!-- modal content -->
        </div>
    
        <div class="modal" id="modal-forgotpassword">
            <!-- modal content -->
        </div>
    
    </div>

</body>
```

In the above, when someone clicks the anchor, you'd see the appropriate modal pop-up. Once you're done with the modal, it hides away until someone needs it again.

My problem with this is that it would mean that every modal needed in the application would always be a part of the DOM regardless of whether it is needed or not.

---

I wanted to know if there is any way of making this process a little more dynamic? This would involve the user clicking the anchor, and the JS code injecting the Modal into the page, and when done, removing the entire modal code from the page.

I assume this would greatly improve load times and render time.

The problem is that I have been unable to understand the logic behind it, I have been doing something very similar with other parts of the project but I have not been able to apply it to the modals. Here's what I assumed would be the jQuery code for injecting the modal

```
$('.ismodal').click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    let modal = $(this).data('modal'),
        elem = '#modal' + modal;

    // Check if element already exists
    if ($(elem).length) {
        $(elem).fadeIn();
    } else {
        
        // Get element code
        let elementCode = functionToGetElementCode(modal);

        // Inject element
        $('#modalContainer').append(elementCode);

        // Fade In element
        $(elem).fadeIn();

    }

});
```

I haven't tried the above code, but I would assume something like the above should work. However, my concern is how I could code the `functionToGetElementCode` such that it would work, and is not terrible difficult to maintain.

I assume the easiest method would be to have the function in which we could have a `switch` function that would filter out the needed code. But is there a way to import the template of each modal from a folder? Something similar to the `include` function in PHP?

Comment: What you want to achieve is client side rendering. You can do it using plain JS via appendChild HTMLNode api. or you can use client side rendering libraries like react, vue etc. But beware that these modals will no longer be visible to search engine crawlers if you want them to get indexed.

Comment: Load the HTML templates for the modals within the page (as you don't save anything by including the templates in a script tag), then remove the elements from the DOM, but keep a reference to the modals alive. Then you can add a modal later to the DOM again. [Something like at this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eanrmzcg/).

Comment: @Teemu I really like your approach, I was also looking into Hitesh's approach about using Ajax calls to get the Modal structure. What do you think about that?

Comment: It's also sometimes used alternative. A con is, that it takes a bit time every time a modal is loaded. You could also combine the two suggestions, load any not-yet-shown modal with AJAX, and then remove it from the DOM when closed (remeber to keep the reference for later use). Or lazy-load all the templates, include them in the `modals` array, and append/remove to/from the DOM when needed (a con being user might try to open a not-yet-loaded modal). You could also utilize [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot), there are a lot of alternatives, just pick yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the `<template>` tag

In html there is a specific tag designed for this use, it's called `<template>`. You can use this tag to store your modals and then render them as needed. You're on the right track but I think there is some confusion about how loading works on the web.

> JS code injecting the Modal into the page ... I assume this would greatly improve load times and render time.

When you think about load times remember the fastest thing to load is plain text. It can be extremely fast and is very very lightweight. JS, on the other hand, will need to be loaded, run, and not error out

### Using AJAX (Not recommended)

If you expect the modal to be infrequently clicked, you could store it in another file and summon it via AJAX. This isn't very advantageous as it will add a network request and processing time to your modal click.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AJAX calls to get the required modal.

Comment: Why is this down voted? This is also one of the ways to solve the given problem, please refer to the accepted reply!